# Google Email Markup not showing event in mail

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

I tried to write an email containing this Google Email Markup, but I don't see the event information:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EventReservation">
<meta itemprop="reservationNumber" content="E123456789"/>
<link itemprop="reservationStatus" href="http://schema.org/Confirmed"/>
<div itemprop="underName" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="John Smith"/>
</div>
<div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Foo Fighters Concert"/>
    <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2027-03-06T19:30:00-08:00"/>
    <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="AT&T Park"/>
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="24 Willie Mays Plaza"/>
        <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="San Francisco"/>
        <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="CA"/>
        <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="94107"/>
        <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="US"/>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

How does Google Email Markup works?

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the registration & whitelisting step?

Your markup can be correct; if your sending address hasn't been signed off on by Google, it won't change users gCalendars, even if the markup is correct.

See:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google